Is this possible to achieve using SQL views?
I have a task to transform a table that has no hierarchy into a view of the table where it will be added two columns (id and parent) this is for establishing parent-child hierarchy and using it to build a visualization of a tree. The data is regarding the classification of tumors made by the WHO organization called ICD 10. In my table, there are no categories yet and my task is to create categories and then add the relation pattern following the classification made by WHO
- C00-C97 :
  C00-C75 
  C76-C80 
  C81-C96 
  C97-C97 
- D00-D09 

- D10-D36 

- D37-D48 

The task is to investigate the feasibility through the use of views otherwise we will alter the original table.
An example of a table:



Uri
Label
timestamp




cim10:c00
text2
text54


cim10:c01
text3
text55


cim10:c02
text4
text56


...
...
...


cim10:c97
text99
text151


cim10:d00
text100
text152


cim10:d01
text101
text153



I have tried something like this (don't mind the categories as this is the original classification):
CREATE VIEW diagnosis_cim10_tumors_view AS
SELECT *
FROM diagnosis
WHERE Uri LIKE 'cim10:C%' 
   OR Uri LIKE 'cim10:D0%'
   OR Uri LIKE 'cim10:D[1-3][0-9]%'
   OR Uri LIKE 'cim10:D4[0-8]%'
   OR Uri LIKE 'cim10:D49%';   

Result I want to achieve, note how the 'child2' Uri was not originally present in the table and has to be added via the query (cim10:D00-D09) . root refers to "classification" label which represent the starting point:



Uri
id
parent




cim10:D00-D09
child2
root


cim10:D00
child2.1
child2


cim10:D01
child2.2
child2


cim10:D02
child2.3
child2


cim10:D03
child2.4
child2


cim10:D04
child2.5
child2


cim10:D05
child2.6
child2


cim10:D06
child2.7
child2


cim10:D07
child2.8
child2


cim10:D09
child2.9
child2




Hi - please don't link to images. Please update your question with the result table you want to achieve, based on the source data you've provided

@NickW good point, will update

Hi - your source table column names and the data it contains don't seem to line up with either the SQL you've written or the result table you're trying to achieve. Please bear in mind that the only information we have about your problem is what you out in your question so please try and express what you are trying to achieve as logically as possible and use clear and consistent data examples to explain any steps

@NickW really appreciate your feedback, indeed it lack a lot of context and details, updated!

OK - but you still have values in the URI column in your source and target that don't match and there's no explanation on where the ones in the target are coming from or how they are being generated. Also, in your source table the other two columns have values like "text%" but these don't appear in your target - so are they relevant to your question and, if so, how? In your target you have columns called id and parent - but no explanation of what they are or how they are created. At the top of your question you have some hierarchical example data - but again no explanation of what this is

the other two columns in my input table are not important and don't  need to be in the output. I have mentioned the use of id and parent for creating hierarchy in the table where id refers to the level of the item in the provided classification made by WHO and parent refers to the parent-class of the current item.
